How do i unban a channel from my groupchat using my pyrogram bot?
I banned my channel from sending messages in a chat using pyrogram's ban_chat_member(), but now I can't unban it. I tried using unban_chat_member() and I still can't send messages as my channel. I can't do it manually either because the channel doesn't show up in the banned users list. What do I do?
code:
banning user/channel:

####some other conditions

            else:
                pending_verification_channel_ids.remove(user_id)
                await message.reply("ban message")
                await client.ban_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=user_id)
                await client.delete_messages(message.chat.id, message.id)
                return

unbanning:

####some other conditions

            try:
                print(f"Unbanning {id_to_unban} in {message.chat.id}")
                await client.unban_chat_member(message.chat.id, id_to_unban)
                await message.reply('Unbanned')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{e}")
                await message.reply('error')

and when I try to unban my channel and give it my channel id as input in the message(it is being decoded correctly), the bot replies with "Unbanned", but I still can't send messages as a channel. When I send the unban command again with the same channel id as input, it replies with 'Unbanned' once again.
